# Importing a CSV with a timestamp field into MonetDB

Tags: csv, timestamp, etl, monetdb

I'm importing a `CSV` into `MonetDB`.  I create a table called fx:

```
CREATE TABLE fx(ticktime timestamp,broker varchar(6),pair varchar(10),side varchar(1),price float,size tinyint,level tinyint)
```

and now I am trying to upload a large `CSV` file that does not have a header.

My sample.csv:

```
 20150828 00:00:00.023,BRK1,EUR/USD,A,1.12437,1,1
 20150828 00:00:00.023,BRK1,EUR/USD,A,1.12439,5,2
 20150828 00:00:00.023,BRK1,EUR/USD,A,1.12441,9,3
```

My command:

```
sql>copy into fx from 'c:\fx\sample.csv' using delimiters ',','\n';
Failed to import table line 1 field 1 'timestamp(7)' expected in '20150828 00:00:00.023'
```

How do I upload this csv?

Answer (score 3):

The timestamp format in your file is not the one MonetDB likes. So two options:

1) Change the type of `ticktime` to `string`:

```
CREATE TABLE fx(ticktime string, broker varchar(6),pair varchar(10),side varchar(1),price float,size tinyint,level tinyint);
COPY INTO ...
```

However, you would then need to convert the string column `ticktime` to a new column `ticktimet` of type timestamp using string manipulation, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE fx add column ticktimet timestamp;
UPDATE fx SET ticktimet=str_to_timestamp(ticktime , '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S');
```

Note that this solution will discard the subsecond part (e.g. `.023`) from the timestamp, as this is currently not supported in `str_to_timestamp`.

2) Change the CSV to use a date format MonetDB likes, e.g.

```
2015-08-28 00:00:00.023,BRK1,EUR/USD,A,1.12437,1,1
2015-08-28 00:00:00.023,BRK1,EUR/USD,A,1.12439,5,2
2015-08-28 00:00:00.023,BRK1,EUR/USD,A,1.12441,9,3
```

Then, `COPY INTO` should work directly.